# Knitr and Figure Caption in HTML

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

knitr defines the argument fig.cap as

> fig.cap: (NULL; character) figure caption to be used in a figure
>   environment in **LaTeX** (in \caption{}); if NULL or NA, it will be
>   ignored, otherwise a figure environment will be used for the plots in
>   the chunk (output in \begin{figure} and \end{figure})

However, for HTML output the following works:

````
---
title: "Caption Test"
author: "Some Author"
date: "February 18, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, fig.cap = c("This is caption 1", "This is caption 2")}
## Plot 1
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds)

## Plot 2
qplot(carat, depth, data = diamonds)
```
````

meaning, each figures gets its correct caption defined in the code chunk argument `fig.cap = c("Caption 1", "Caption 2")`

However, it is challenging to keep track of captions -especially if long- when they are placed inside the chunk options.  Besides creating two separate chunks for each figure with captions inserted outside of the chunk, are there other options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `eval.after="fig.cap"` so that figure captions are evaluated *after* the chunk is run. That way, you can define your captions inside the chunk.

````
---
title: "Caption Test"
author: "Some Author"
date: "February 18, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = 'fig.cap')
```

```{r, fig.cap = cap}
## Plot 1
qplot(carat, price, data = diamonds)
cap <- "This is caption 1"

## Plot 2
qplot(carat, depth, data = diamonds)

cap <- c(cap, "This is caption 2")
```
````

Comment: This will be the default in the next version of knitr: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/e3e3e1b8e3640707e03af2b521159abb8b214d70